# How can I check a variable entered by user is a number (int, float)?

Tags: rust

How can I check a variable (entered by user) is a number such as an int, float, or something else?

I want to do this with a `match` expression:

```
let mut input = String::new();
io::stdin().read_line(&mut input);
let result = match input {
    // !!??     
}
```

is it possible by `match`?

Comment: It is a **very** bad idea to ignore the `Result` returned from `read_line`.

Comment: @Shepmaster: "very" is relative, in a one-off script it may not matter :)

Comment: @MatthieuM. nah, I'll be an extremist in this case: it's **never** acceptable to ignore errors. It's a simple thing to *handle* the error (`.expect("Could not read input")`). For a one-off script, I agree that **aborting** is a reasonable way to handle the error, as opposed to something more user-friendly.

Comment: I agree with @Shepmaster - `unwrap()` is trivial to write even in a one-off script, and it can save you serious pain in cases where the error would have otherwise gone undetected.

Comment: @user4815162342 and I'll always advocate for `expect` over `unwrap`, just so when the failure occurs it's much easier to find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to match against something then you need something to destructure on.  You can match against string slices, but only a finite set, so that doesn't help here.

So let's have an enum to match on:

```
enum Value {
    Int(isize),
    Float(f64),
}
use Value::*;  // Make the variants available without Value::
```

Then you need to parse the string into the appropriate type.  You can use the [`parse`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse) method for each type (if you're happy with Rust's syntax for those; otherwise you might need a fancier parser):

```
fn parse_string(s: &str) -> Option<Value> {
    if let Ok(i) = s.parse() {  // inferred as isize from next line
        Some(Int(i))
    } else if let Ok(f) = s.parse() {
        Some(Float(f))
    } else {
        None
    }
}
```

Note that when trying parses in sequence like this the order matters; `"123"` would parse as an `f64` too.

I'm turning any parse errors into `None` and using `Option` rather than `Result` because it's not clear what the error would be (since each parse can return its own); in a real application I might have a `ParseError` type.

Now we can match on the result:

```
fn main() {
    let x = "123";
    match parse_string(x) {
        Some(Int(i)) => println!("int {}", i),
        Some(Float(f)) => println!("float {}", f),
        None => println!("Didn't parse"),
    }
    let x = "123.5";
    match parse_string(x) {
        Some(Int(i)) => println!("int {}", i),
        Some(Float(f)) => println!("float {}", f),
        None => println!("Didn't parse"),
    }
}
```

[Runnable playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=20f6e93a5223ef748c24f8e583699589&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Comment: The inference in those `if let` bindings is quite extraordinary. I mean that in a good way - I learned something from this. Thanks!